# Is it possible to create changelog in Teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

Basically just like title says - I am wondering if it is possible to create changelog on TeamCity based on the commits name?

Comment: Basically, using `Command line` build step you can run any script you want. It would be better to ask more specific question to get better answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create changelog artifact in TeamCity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317409/create-changelog-artifact-in-teamcity)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as long as you have proper issue tracker integration configured.

Navigate to Project overview and select "Issue Log" tab. There you can filter the list of fixed issues based on build numbers and download resulting view in CSV format.